# Issues with Unity and Gnome

Tags: 12.04, unity, desktop-environments

Usually my computer loaded the desktop on ubuntu, however starting today, I can not load the desktop. The only interface I can get, is if I click the power button (physical) it takes me to the shutdown menu.

However LXDE works perfectly as normal so I dont believe it is a disk-based issue.

Please Help and Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem!
I upgraded to quantal, then to raring,saucy, and finally trusty tahr (LTS 14.04). 
It works and everything is good as new now. Even though i wasted another 10 hours doing so.

Comment: How nice .I will do it when i got this problem . tnx